# Как оставить свойство hover родительскому элементу в выпадающем меню, при наведении на дочерний?

Tags: html, css, hover

[image: Пример]

```css
.menu ul,
.menu ol {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu > ul{
   display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu > ul li a {
    display:block;
    background: linear-gradient(0,#773607, #e5c265);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .5s;

}

.menu > ul li{
    position: relative;

}

.allign{

    padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #9a4f19;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

.menu li a:hover{
    background-image:linear-gradient(0, #eadebe, #e5c265, #eadebe );
    color: #4a2810;
    transition: all .5s;
}

/*SUBMENU*/


.menu li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 200px;
    left: -40px;
}

.menu li > ul li a:hover{

    background: #e5b36f;
}

.menu li > ul li{
    border-left: 1px solid #9a4f19;
    border-right: 1px solid #9a4f19;
}

.menu li > ul li a{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffdda6;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #4a2810;
}

.border_bottom{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9a4f19
}

.menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="allign" href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
            <li><a class="allign" href="#">ПОДОБРАТЬ ПЕРСОНАЛ</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">О Нас</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Задать вопрос</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Это интересно</a></li>
                <li><a class="border_bottom" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
              </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a class="allign" href="#">ЦЕНЫ</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы обрабатываете `hover a`, который является потомком `.menu li` (наведение только на ссылку)

```
.menu li a:hover
```

А нужно - при `li: hover`, в дочернем элементе `a` (наведение на весь элемент списка)

```
.menu li:hover > a
```

```css
.menu ul,
.menu ol {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu > ul{
   display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu > ul li a {
    display:block;
    background: linear-gradient(0,#773607, #e5c265);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .5s;

}

.menu > ul li{
    position: relative;

}

.allign{

    padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #9a4f19;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

.menu li:hover > a{
    background-image:linear-gradient(0, #eadebe, #e5c265, #eadebe );
    color: #4a2810;
    transition: all .5s;
}

/*SUBMENU*/


.menu li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 200px;
    left: -40px;
}

.menu li > ul li a:hover{

    background: #e5b36f;
}

.menu li > ul li{
    border-left: 1px solid #9a4f19;
    border-right: 1px solid #9a4f19;
}

.menu li > ul li a{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffdda6;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #4a2810;
}

.border_bottom{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9a4f19
}

.menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="allign" href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
            <li><a class="allign" href="#">ПОДОБРАТЬ ПЕРСОНАЛ</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">О Нас</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Задать вопрос</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Это интересно</a></li>
                <li><a class="border_bottom" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
              </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a class="allign" href="#">ЦЕНЫ</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
```